# remove only position relative inline style using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have inline style

```
<div class="handle" id="parent4" value="3" size="large" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 0; cursor: pointer;"></div>
```

i want remove the position relative style in tha above code using jquery

```
<div class="handle" id="parent4" value="3" size="large" style= top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 0; cursor: pointer;"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to override the position with `static`,

```
$('#parent4').css('position','static');
```

since `static` is the default position for any div elements.

Answer (score 3):

For removing style, you can use `.css(stylename,'')` syntax.So in your case use this:

```
$('#parent4').css('position','');
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the position to static, that's the default value.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code to remove

```
(function($)
    {
        $.fn.removeStyle = function(style)
        {
            var search = new RegExp(style + '[^;]+;?', 'g');

            return this.each(function()
            {
                $(this).attr('style', function(i, style)
                {
                    return style.replace(search, '');
                });
            });
        };
    }(jQuery));
```

Using this mini plugin you can write in your JS file

```
$('#element').removeStyle('position');
```